# Calculate percentage of specific grouped values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by, count

I have a dataframe:

```
id       is_good
a1        1
a1        1
a1        0
bb        1
bb        0
bb        0
bb        0
с1        0
с1        0
d2        1
d2        1
```

As you see there are cases when id value has only type of is_good. I want to count percentage of 0 and 1 for each id. And if id value has only type of is_good, the type that he hasn't must be 0 percent. The same with d2. So desired result is:

```
id       is_good_perc
a1        0.67
bb        0.25
с1        0
d2        1
```

How to do that? The tricky part for me is case with id c1 and d2.

I tried this:

```
.groupby("id").is_good.value_count(normalize=True)
```

but it doesn't create 0 for c1 and d2

Comment: Shouldn't `a1` be `0.5`?

Comment: @Jab no there are two 1 and one 0, so its 2/3

Comment: df.groupby(df.id).mean()

Comment: @JosephDoun it says ```DataError: No numeric types to aggregate```

Comment: @french_fries your "is_good" columns is of string type then. You have to turn it into either int or float. e.g. df['is_good'] = df['is_good'].astype(int). Look at the output of df.info().

Answer (score 0):

You group `df.is_good` by `df.id` then divide the sum by the count:

```
>>> grouped = df['is_good'].groupby(df.id)
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(grouped.sum() / grouped.count()).round(2).rename(columns={'is_good': 'is_good_perc'})
>>> df1 
    is_good_perc
id              
a1          0.67
bb          0.25
d2          1.00
с1          0.00
```

Comment: it brings this error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str